# Ring norms and spectral radius

Tags: ring-theory, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a ring, $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$ two norms on $A$, equivalent to each others (as norms on the ring $A$).

Can we say that they have the same spectral radius (with respect to each norm) ? i.e. $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$

Comment: What do you mean by the spectral radius with respect to a norm?

Comment: For all $f \in A$ : 

$\sigma_1 (f) = lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} (||f^n||_1)^\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sigma_2 (f) = lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} (||f^n||_2)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula.